# how to get different types of statements by only using java model in JDT not AST?

Tags: java, eclipse-jdt

There is a class named "Statement" in package org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.Statement. However, it extends ASTNode. Can I use the class Statement in Java Model which defined in JDT instead of AST? And how to use it? Thanks!

Comment: It is very unclear what you are asking here. ASTNode is part of org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom. Eclipse JDT uses the Abstract Syntax Tree code for pretty much everything.

Comment: Yeah~ I know, but I do not want to use AST. In JDT, it defined two ways to get structure, Java model and AST. I would like to get statements by using Java model, is it possible to use Class statement but not use AST?

Comment: My understanding is that the Java Model only covers those things that the JDT UI code needs. Statements are not included in that.

Comment: okay~ I see. Thanks!

Comment: Right, @greg-449, Java Model is more coarse grained than AST, much of the UI works on Java Model, model elements can be searched for, don't require parsing of method bodies, are light weight handles that are populated on demand - these are just a few different ways of describing the difference.